# html dropdown list options

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have the following drop down menu on my website

```
<select name="Templates"  onchange="document.sendform.message.value = 'some text here'; return false;">
<option value="#" selected>----Templates----</option>
<option value="#">Absense</option>
<option value="#">Lates</option>

</select>
```

This currently sends text to a text area named "message" however I would like the text to be different for each option selected. Is there an easy way to do this at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the text as the option value, and then write the value of the selected option to your textarea …

Answer (score 4):

Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/sinisake/3NQH7/

```
 <form name="sendform">
    <select name="Templates"  onchange="document.sendform.message.value = this.value; return false;">
    <option value="#" selected>----Templates----</option>
    <option value="absense">Absense</option>
    <option value="lates">Lates</option>

        <input type="text" value="" name="message" />
    </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `onchange` event handler is what sends the text; if you want to send text based on the value of the selected option you should use a more advanced event handler:

```
document.TemplateForm.Templates.onchange = function () {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value === 'absence') {
        setMessage('Absence message');
    } else if (value === 'laters') {
        setMessage('Laters message');
    } else {
        setMessage('Default message');   
    }
    return false;
};

function setMessage(message) {
    document.sendform.message.value = message;
}
```

I wrapped your `select` element in a form to be able to adress it simply in the JavaScript above:

```
<form name="TemplateForm">
    <select name="Templates">
        <option value="#" selected>----Templates----</option>
        <option value="absence">Absense</option>
        <option value="laters">Lates</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

In order to see what value is selected I also added unique values for the `options` elements.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/fRB3s/1/